# General solution for saving and retrieving different files in sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, file, stream

I know how to store images to db (convert them to byte[] and then save it) and also for retrieving (select byte[] from db and use image methods to create image from byte[]). I'm cool so far, but how can I save/retrieve a PDF to database? What about `.doc` , `.mp3` , `.exe` and say `.ppt` files?

Is there a general way to save and retrieve files to and from sql server? The worst part is retrieving, let's imagine we found a way to save any file to sql server, now how can we rebuild the file from db? We don't know what the file extension was before saving?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Generally speaking, it's considered bad practice to save actual files to the database.
a part of the reason is the problems you mentioned in your post, and an even bigger part is that saving files directly to the database has a large overhead (such as translating an image to a byte array and back).

the easy (and recommended in most cases) way to handle files and databases is to save the files directly to the file system, and keep the path in the database along with other file-related data such as the user id that uploaded the file.

this way you don't need to worry about braking and rebuilding the files, you just send them to the server and back to the user as is.

Keep in mind it's not recommended to keep the full path of the file, only a relative path.

What I normally do is save all files from the users either on the serer itself or on the users's computer (in a desktop application). in any of these cases, there is a dedicated folder with only read/write permissions **(NEVER let a user save a file into a directory with execute permissions!)**, and keep the path of this directory either on a 'General Params' table in the database or in the configuration file of the website / application / webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the file attributes (name, extension, author, etc) are usually kept in relational way, in table inside SQL Server. The file itself should be kept in SQL Server database, exactly how depends on version od SQL Server and size of file. Use FILESTREAM or FILETABLES feature for larger, or VARBINARY(MAX) for smaller files.

It doesn't matter whether its an image, or doc or pdf -- if you car read into a FileStream, you can save it to database.

Advantages of storing files in a database is simplified management, backups, security, integrity. With FILESTREAM and FILETABLES feature, accessing a file is almost the same as if it were on a file system, using the SqlFileStream object from .NET.

See more here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

And here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx